# Using fancybox + fullscreen option

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fullscreen

in my [website](http://arthurnn.com/cris/), I have some images which I am displaying them inside a fancybox. Everything working ok, but now the requirement of the website is to have a Fullscreen mode for the photos, What I mean by fullscreen is I want a add a button at the bottom of my fancybox, and when the user click on that button, the current image(fancybox image) has to be displayed in fullscreen mode.

Example of fullscreen: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

But this example doesnt fit in my situation because I still need the fancybox before the fullscreen mode.

So someone has some code to share or some good library that I can do that integration btw jQuery Fancybox and some fullscreen api?
thanks

Comment: "...show the image as fullscreen!" - what do you mean? Please, describe the behavior in case an image dimensions are smaller than screen, bigger than screen and image proportion and screen proportion aren't the same.

Comment: there is no small images. I have all the images in large sizes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following steps will do what you're looking for:

1. See the following URL to learn how to add a custom button to Fancybox: [Adding custom buttons to jQuery's fancybox](http://nsdiv.blogspot.com/2010/05/adding-custom-buttons-to-jquerys.html).  It will take a bit of effort but it does work.
2. When first showing the Fancybox, hook the custom button to launch fullscreen mode. Use the [Supersized plug-in](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/).
3. The div used to show the Supersized images will be hidden on the page and you'll show the Supersize div when launching fullscreen.
4. Add a "close" button to the Supersized div and hide the div when clicked

The above steps will do it.  There is a bit of customization required for both Fancybox and Supersized but you will be able to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: Tried this today, the first link's instructions are tailored for jquery.fancybox-1.3.1 so if you have a version 2.1.5+ this will not apply for you.