# How can I make css3 opening div?

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I want to make FullScreen opening div with CSS3. When I click the button, it will open fullscreen but not for images. I use it for contact, about pages.

For example this page's links "about us, contact us, newslettre" http://abyadwaswad.com/Vipe/index-image.html

Comment: Take a look at [fencyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

Comment: @Vucko thank you but this is not fullscreen.

Comment: might be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589080/using-fancybox-fullscreen-option

Comment: This Might be helpfull [Full Screen overlay](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/)